# Assigning dynamic ids to elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am using jQuery and creating tags in a loop.

Ex -

```
for(var i=0;i<length;i++){

            jQuery("#dailydata").append("<table class='table'><tr>"+
                "<th>Min Temp : </th><td>"+ data[i]</td>" +
                "</tr></table>";

                if(data[i] <=10){
                    //add color to th
                }else{
                    //add different color to th
                }
        }
```

I am creating a Table Row in every loop and appending to a HTML element. and just after that I am checking the value and according to that value I want to change the background color of the  tag.

Can somebody tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: err I dont actually get what you mean

Comment: Your question isn't really very clear.

Comment: Why do you need IDs? Using JS to add an ID just so that you can later select the same element by ID is generally unnecessary. Why can't you set the colour at the time you create the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods.

The method you're using to build the tags isn't the most elegant, but you could adapt it to achieve the result you're after as follows...

```
jQuery("#dailydata").append("<table class='table'><tr>"+
            "<th id='"+ (data[i]<=10?'blue':'red') + "'>Min Temp : </th><td>"+ data[i]</td>" +
            "</tr></table>";
```

I suggest you also read the jQuery docs on how to use 'attr' and 'prop' to add id's (and other attributes/properties) to jQuery elements without hacking the text together as in my example.

jQuery 'attr': https://api.jquery.com/attr/

jQuery 'prop': https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Thank you it solved my prob and thank you for the links.

Comment: If I run this it will have multiple `th` with same `Id`, which is completely against the standard

Comment: True.  But it is fine if @Akki is only using the id's as a means of identifying the th to set the relevant color.  Otherwise, then instead of ```id=''```, the using ```class=``` (or even, ```data-color=``` or similar) would work just as well without breaking the standard.  If the id's really need to function as unique id's, then I can propose another solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way basing on your code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  var color;
  if(data[i] <=10) {
    color = "ff0000";
  } else{
    color = "0000ff";
  }

  jQuery("#dailydata").append(
    "<table class='table'><tr>" +
    "<th style="background-color:#" + color + 
    ">Min Temp : </th><td>" + data[i]</td>" +
    "</tr></table>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an extra if condition to check the value of i

Here in this example , assume length is value greater than `i`. Also in your example you are using `data[i]` but the loop will run on `length` variable.There is a typo here `data[i]</td>"` It need to be `data[i]+"</td>"`. Also the `append` method be closed with `)`

```js
var length = 15;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

  if (i < 10) {
    jQuery("#dailydata").append("<table class='table'><tr>" +
      "<th class='less10'>Min Temp : </th><td>" + i + "</td>" +
      "</tr></table>");
  } else {
    jQuery("#dailydata").append("<table class='table'><tr>" +
      "<th class='more10'>Min Temp : </th><td>" + i + "</td>" +
      "</tr></table>");
  }

}
```

```css
.less10 {
  color: green
}

.more10 {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dailydata">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly:**

You should not use numeric values (0,1,2,3,etc) for ids. The [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) say this:

*ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").*

**Secondly:**

Your code is weight... Did you create a variable called "length" in lines not shown in your example? I assume in your for loop you meant `i<data.length`

So with that in mind use an alphabetical prefix to your ids:

```
// Note jQuery("#dailydata") same as $("#dailydata") unless you override the use of the "$" symbol

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var newElementId = "some_prefix_"+i;

    var newElementToAppend = $("<div>").attr("id", newElementId);
    $("#dailydata").append(newElementToAppend);
}
```